# MySQL 8 does not use the provided config files

Tags: mysql, galera

I am installing Galera 4 on top of MySQL 8 on Debian but can't make it work. Once I start first node with bootstrap command:

```
mysqld_bootstrap
```

it starts with the following options:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld $$'$\'$\\\'--wsrep-new-cluster --wsrep-on\\\'\'' --wsrep_start_position=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
```

Problem is there is no pid file created and even though it appears to be running and I can't connect to the database.
There is nothing going to the log file either so I think it is ommiting the config files.

I have tried running config validator:

```
mysqld --validate_config
```

but it hangs on futex (checked with strace). In both cases it is not possible to kill mysqld normally and -9 option has to be used.

LXC is used to run this instance with following kernel:

*Linux node01 4.15.18-26-pve #1 SMP PVE 4.15.18-54 (Sat, 15 Feb 2020 15:34:24 +0100) x86_64 GNU/Linux*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was pretty obvious after some investigation. No rsync used to sync the cluster was installed on the nodes so they can't sync together.